# Fancybox on checkbox showing an iFrame

Tags: jquery, fancybox

Currently I'm working on a advertisement website where people can sign-up their company/accomodation. So now I made a checkbox where people have to accept it before you can register your compny. Because an window.load() will not work for every browser (ie > popupblocker etc.) I've got to find another way.

Fancybox supports showing iFramed content inside their fancy box (how fine!).
This is working on a simple a href.. now I want to accomplish the same results at a checkbox.
When people select the checkbox, the Terms and conditions should be showed inside the fancy box. T&C are saved inside a html side.

```
    $("#plaatsing").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': true
    });
    });
```

The code above works for a `<a href="">` , not for a checkbox..
Can somebody help me with this problem?

When i apply the plaatsing ID on my checkbox, it shows a nice checkbox inside the fancybox. How can I make it show the .html page?

---

### EDIT

Found a solution for FF + Chrome.. not working in IE ofc.

JS:

```
 $("a#controle").fancybox({
      'hideOnContentClick': true
 });
```

HTML:

```
input onclick="$('a#controle').trigger('click');" name="plaatsing" id="plaatsing" type="checkbox" />
```

Works.. but not for IE :'(!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you use `#("#plaatsing")` with `.click()` ?

```
$(function(){
      $("#plaatsing").click(function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')) $('a#controle').trigger('click');
      });
});
```

Or I think you can use `.change()` too instead of `.click()`!

Just I used checkbox before for agreement box, that if that checkbox checked, show register link, so I think that will work with you "Hopefully that", but I'm not sure if the same way will work with fancybox & `.trigger()`, I read that `.trigger()` has a problem with `"onclick"` with IE or something like that, anyway try my solution :)